# babel-plugin-react-css-modules cannot resolve scss files using aliased path in webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass, babel-plugin-react-css-modules

I am trying to use `babel-plugin-react-css-modules` in a react app with webpack and SSR. However the aliased import statements shows `Cannot find module` error in webpack.
If i use relative path for the scss file like `../../styles/file.module.scss` then webpack is able to resolve it.

Comment: How is `babel-plugin-react-css-modules` related to `webpack`?